# Como cambiar color de los "td" de una fila de acuerdo al valor que posee

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Deseo cambiar el color del td de una tabla  de aguerdo al dato que posee, la tabla se genero a través de un foreach pero solo funciona en la primera columna de la tabla mas no se aplica a toda la fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<script>
      var est =document.getElementById('estado').innerHTML;
      function cambiarcolor(){
        if (est=="VIGENTE") {
          document.getElementById('estado').style.color="green";
        }
        if (est=="FINALIZADO") {
          document.getElementById('estado').style.color="green";
        }
      }
      cambiarcolor();
</script>
```

```html
@foreach ($convocatorias as $conv)
<tr>
  <td>{{$conv->idconvocatoria}}</td>
  <td>{{$conv->descripcion}}</td>
  <td>PDF</td>
  <td>{{$conv->fecha_publicacion}}</td>
  <td>{{$conv->fecha_vencimiento}}</td>
  <td id="estado">{{$conv->estado}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Espero puedan ayudarme gracias de antemano

Comment: Yo lo que haria seria, en el php comprobar que tipo de estado tiene y en funcion de eso meterle al `<td>` un `class` con el color que quieres, despues en un archivo `css` crear las class con el color correspondiente. Con esto te quitas el `js`.

Comment: Tu problmea ademas, si no me equivoco es que estas usando un `id` para algo que se repite y en el `js` solo esta cogiendo el primer elemento... Ademas ten cuidado porque estas poneindo en que los dos casos el color es `green`

Comment: `<td class="estado-{{strtolower($conv->estado)}}">{{$conv->estado}}</td>` te va a ir imprimiedo las clases `estado-finalizado`, `estado-vigente`, etc luego por css le cambias el color a esa class

Answer (score 0):

Detecto varios problemas al analizar el código que presentas.

Primeramente veo que estas usando un id `estado` para todos y cada uno de los elementos de la tabla cuando los id deberían ser únicos en el HTML. De esta manera `getElementById` solo recibe el primero de todos los que tienen este id puesto que `getElementById` siempre devuelve un único elemento.

Para solucionar esto manteniendo en la medida de lo posible tu código actual yo cambiaría el id por `class="estado"` y así podrás utilizar

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('estado')].forEach(item => ...);
```

o también puedes usar

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.estado')].forEach(item => ...);
```

añadiendo la validación de colores según estado dentro del `forEach`.

Por otra parte y tal y como se ha mencionado en alguno de los comentarios de la pregunta yo lo haría en el propio foreach de php sustituyendo esta línea (`<td id="estado">{{$conv->estado}}</td>`) por

```
<td class="{{ strtolower($conv->estado) }}">{{$conv->estado}}</td>
```

y en un archivo `css` metería los estilos en base a los diferentes estados posibles como por ejemplo:

```
.vigente { 
   color: green; 
}
.finalizado { color: grey; }
.pendiente{ color: blue; }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código solo tienes dos posibles de estado, entonces yo lo resolveria de una manera mas simple asi...

```
@foreach ($convocatorias as $conv)
<tr>
  <td>{{$conv->idconvocatoria}}</td>
  <td>{{$conv->descripcion}}</td>
  <td>PDF</td>
  <td>{{$conv->fecha_publicacion}}</td>
  <td>{{$conv->fecha_vencimiento}}</td>
  <td>
     @if($conv->estado == 'VIGENTE')
       <span style="color:green;">{{$conv->estado}}</span>
     @else
       <span style="color:#000000;">{{$conv->estado}}</span>
     @endif
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```